# Take advantage of JSON flexibility in Java components

Tags: java, json, couchbase

I am just trying to find a way to be more flexible.
I have a java web-app that connects to a noSql db (couchbase). In order to map the stored jsons I have created a jar which contains all the java classes for all those jsons.

Rex json document

```
{
  "age":15
}
```

Mapping the json structure to java class:

```
public class Dog{

  private int age;
  // getters+setters
}
```

The problem I am facing is:

Whenever I update the db json structure (because json is flexible) I have to update also the java classes -> recompile a new jar version of the classes (and update the web-app dependency to the new jar version).

A newly needed update for Rex json:

```
{
  "dob":"1999/01/25",
  "name":"Rex"
}
```

I need an update to the Dog class looking like this:

```
public class Dog{

  private String dob;
  private String name;
  // getters+setters
}
```

How can I create the java classes to be flexibleand to not need a new recompilation of the classes jar?
My main objective is to not update/redeploy the web-apps connecting to noSql in case of an update of json structure.

Hoping this is not a dumb question, I thank you,
Georgian

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Map<String, String>` for storing these values

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create the java classes to be flexibleand to not need a new recompilation of the classes jar?

I assume that you need to read and write JSON using these classes ...

If so, you need to choose between:

- a JSON <-> Java binding (like you are currently using) where you will need to generate new Java classes when your JSON structures change, OR
- a JSON binding that binds JSON "objects" to a `Map` type, OR
- something like the old "org.json" library where you load JSON into a `JSONObject`.

There is no way to get a statically typed API (like your `Dog` class) that automagically deals with changing JSON structures.